# how to find consecutive repetitive characters in oracle column

Tags: regex, oracle

Is there any way to find consecutive repetitive characters  like 1414, 200200 in a varchar column of an oracle table.
how can we achieve it with regexp ?

Im failing to achieve it with regexp 
im my example i can get a consecutive repetition of a number but not a pattern

select regexp_substr('4120066' ,'([[:alnum:]])\1', 7,1,'i') from dual; -- getting output as expected

select regexp_substr('6360360' ,'([[:alnum:]])\1', 7,1,'i') from dual;  -- i want to select this also as i have 360 followed by 360

Comment: Just to clarify, the 0 within 200 should not be counted as a set of repetitive characters?

Comment: yes. here im treating 200 as a set

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
[...] WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(field, '(\d+?)\1')
```

If you're looking for any repetition of characters, or:

```
[...] WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(field, '^(\d+?)\1$')
```

If you want to check the whole string in the field.

`\d+?` will match digits.

`( ... )` will store those digits.

`\1` refers to the captured digits.

Note: Change to `\d` to `.` if you are not checking digits only.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
SQL> WITH t AS
  2           (SELECT '1414,200200,11,12,33,33,1234,1234' test_string
  3              FROM DUAL)
  4      SELECT     LTRIM (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (test_string, ','), ',') names
  5            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY test_string) rno, test_string
  6                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (test_string,
  7                                                         '[^,]+',
  8                                                         1,
  9                                                         LEVEL
 10                                                       ) test_string
 11                                    FROM t
 12                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 13                                              LENGTH (test_string)
 14                                            - LENGTH (REPLACE (test_string,
 15                                                               ',',
 16                                                               NULL
 17                                                              )
 18                                                     )
 19                                           + 1))
 20          WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 AND ROWNUM = 1
 21     CONNECT BY rno = PRIOR rno + 1;

NAMES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11,12,1234,1414,200200,33
```

None of the delimited string repeat !